# Conceptos POO PHP - Error: Call to undefined method

Tags: php

Tengo un problema y también la duda, al importar o extender clases en PHP.

Tengo un Trait (FeatureTestTrait.php) el cuál importo en una clase Auth.php
Esta Clase Auth.php la importo a su vez en otra clase TestApi.php:

```
use .....\....\FeatureTestTrait;

class Auth 
{
    use FeatureTestTrait;

    public function getToken(): string
    {
        //... 
    }
}
```

---

```
use .....\...\Auth;

class TestApi extends CIUnitTestCase
{
    public function testToken()
    {
        $auth = new Auth();
        $token = $auth->getToken();
        //...         
    }
}
```

y obtengo el error: Error: Call to undefined method .....\Auth::getPrivateProperty().

getPrivateProperty() está definido en FeatureTestTrait.php:

```
protected function populateGlobals(string $method, Request $request, array $params = null)
    {
        $get = ! empty($params) && $method === 'get'
            ? $params
            : $this->getPrivateProperty($request->uri, 'query');
        //...
```

Lo que no entiendo es que si extiendo Auth.php en TestApi.php en vez de importarla y accedo a la función getToken() con $this->getToken() no obtengo el error:

```
use ...\...\FeatureTestTrait;
use ...\...\CIUnitTestCase;

abstract class Auth extends CIUnitTestCase
{
    use FeatureTestTrait;

    protected function token(): string
    {
       //...
    }
}
```

---

```
use ...\...\Auth;

final class TestApi extends Auth 
{

    public function testToken()
    {
        $token =  $this->token();
        //...        
    }
}
```

Pero querría es extender TestApi de CIUnitTestCase.

Muchas gracias de ante mano.

Comment: que es esto?? .....\....\

Comment: Te recomiendo que pases a la lecturas de los siguientes artículos: 
[ask] y 
[mre] y 
[help/on-topic] y 
[help/dont-ask]

Comment: no veo en el código donde se declara este método, ni donde lo estas implementando `getPrivateProperty`

Comment: @FranciscoNúñez-TodoPoderoso son las rutas de los namespace, no consideré importante esa infoprmación.  getPrivateProperty() esta en  el archivo FeatureTestTrait.php pero no encontré donde está definido. 
Este Trait es de phpUnit. Leeré la documentación que me adjuntó para elaborar las preguntas correctamente.

Comment: intentaste con self::???